# WCF connection issues: Config setup

Tags: c#, wcf

Could not connect to https: //service. TCP error code 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 10.30.82.99:443.

I have 2 config files as follows:

Server:

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="Olap.Service.OlapService" behaviorConfiguration="sb">
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="end" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBind" contract="Olap.Service.IOlapService" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="sb">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="end">
                    <webHttp />
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="webBind">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Client:

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://service" binding="basicHttpBinding"
             bindingConfiguration="webBind" contract="Olap.Service.OlapService.IOlapService"
             name="ServiceWcf" />
        </client>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="webBind">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

I added a service reference and in when trying to call methods on the OlapServiceClient object i create (new OlapServiceClient("ServiceWcf") i get the exception. I have been looking through other similar questions asked but nothing has worked. I presume from those others that my set up for bindings on the server must be same as client. It also does not work if i change the link to be http i then get an exception with the message "The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'.
Parameter name: via" which i have also seen many pages on here about but have not been able to fix myself. The inner exception says "Unable to connect to remote server". Cheers

Comment: Have you actually tried googling the TCP error code? There's a lot of information out there about it, many people find it's down to an actual network error where the ports aren't open or because you've not set the proxy information in your config e.g. http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2010/01/04/resolving-the-ldquotcp-error-code-10060-a-connection-attempt-failedhelliprdquo.aspx

Comment: yes i have looked at that specific link and had a play around with it. I will give it another go. Cheers

Comment: maybe its to do with my proxyaddress settings. Unsure about what to actually put as the address and port